# jQuery not minifying in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.Net MVC.

For some reason my JS files are NOT minifying.  My CSS is minifying fine.

My CSS minifies to: `<link href="/ffee/content/css?v=vaNo49ei5GzRQAYnj-AD-AbQI3GKNs2OZ8q6-oJEEvk1" rel="stylesheet">` but all of my JS files are listed separately in the source.

I am compiling and publishing in Release mode.

Can anyone please advise on how I can resolve this please?

Thank you,

Mark

BootstrapBundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace BootstrapSupport
{
public class BootstrapBundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-combobox.js",
             "~/Scripts/select2.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/mt").Include(
           "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                            "~/Scripts/mtDateEdit.js",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-te-1.4.0.js"
                            //"~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js"
                            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/body.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-mvc-validation.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-combobox.css",
             "~/Content/select2.css",
            "~/Content/datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-te-1.4.0.css"
            ));
    }
}
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);

        BootstrapMvcSample.ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        RegisterViewMapper();
    }
```

_Bootstrap.Layout.Basic.cshtml - at the bottom of the file:

```
 <div class="container">
     @Scripts.Render("~/js")
     @Scripts.Render("~/mt")
     @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

     @Html.Partial("_alerts")
     @Html.Partial("_validationSummary")
     @RenderBody()   

 </div>
```

Comment: Are you in `debug` or `release` mode?

Comment: Hi - Release mode.  My CSS minifies to:  <link href="/ffee/content/css?v=vaNo49ei5GzRQAYnj-AD-AbQI3GKNs2OZ8q6-oJEEvk1" rel="stylesheet"/> - but all of my JS files are listed separately in the source.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Did you try forcing it with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

Comment: Hi @lalibi - thank you that worked.  Looks like there are minification errors, and thats perhaps why it didn't work automatically.  Please post an answer, and I'll mark is as such.  Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing it with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

If there are minification/bundling errors, as you state, remove one by one the `*.js` files from the bundle, until you find the offending one. Once you do find it, try adding a linefeed to the top and the end of this file.

Answer (score 2):

You can force it for only release mode just add below code in Application_Start

```
 #if RELEASE            
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;            
 #endif
```